# Can TNEF be avoided using MAPI?

Tags: delphi, exchange-server, mapi

I am using [this code](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234623/how-to-send-a-mapi-email-with-an-attachment-to-a-fax-recipient) to send emails through MAPI using Delphi.

A few users who use Microsoft mailing software report that the receipants receive emails with an attachment **WinMail.dat**. I know that this is an issue with Microsoft Exchange/Outlook and can be corrected by disabling RTF/TNEF. (I don't know for sure because I do not use Microsoft mailing software).

My question is, if I can tell the mailing software to not use TNEF using the MAPI.

```
function SendEMailUsingMAPI(const Subject, Body, FileName, SenderName, SenderEMail, RecipientName, RecipientEMail: string): Integer;
var
  Message: TMapiMessage;
  lpSender, lpRecipient: TMapiRecipDesc;
  FileAttach: TMapiFileDesc;
  SM: TFNMapiSendMail;
  MAPIModule: HModule;
  FileType: TMapiFileTagExt;
begin
  // Source: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234623/how-to-send-a-mapi-email-with-an-attachment-to-a-fax-recipient
  // Modified

  FillChar(Message,SizeOf(Message),0);

  if (Subject <> '') then begin
    Message.lpszSubject := PChar(Subject);
  end;

  if (Body <> '') then begin
    Message.lpszNoteText := PChar(Body);
  end;

  if (SenderEmail <> '') then
  begin
    lpSender.ulRecipClass := MAPI_ORIG;
    if (SenderName = '') then begin
      lpSender.lpszName := PChar(SenderEMail);
    end
    else begin
      lpSender.lpszName := PChar(SenderName);
    end;
    lpSender.lpszAddress := PChar('smtp:'+SenderEmail);
    lpSender.ulReserved := 0;
    lpSender.ulEIDSize := 0;
    lpSender.lpEntryID := nil;
    Message.lpOriginator := @lpSender;
  end;

  if (RecipientEmail <> '') then
  begin
    lpRecipient.ulRecipClass := MAPI_TO;
    if (RecipientName = '') then begin
      lpRecipient.lpszName := PChar(RecipientEMail);
    end
    else begin
      lpRecipient.lpszName := PChar(RecipientName);
    end;
    lpRecipient.lpszAddress := PChar('smtp:'+RecipientEmail);
    lpRecipient.ulReserved := 0;
    lpRecipient.ulEIDSize := 0;
    lpRecipient.lpEntryID := nil;
    Message.nRecipCount := 1;
    Message.lpRecips := @lpRecipient;
  end
  else begin
    Message.lpRecips := nil;
  end;

  if (FileName = '') then begin
    Message.nFileCount := 0;
    Message.lpFiles := nil;
  end
  else begin
    FillChar(FileAttach,SizeOf(FileAttach),0);
    FileAttach.nPosition := Cardinal($FFFFFFFF);
    FileAttach.lpszPathName := PChar(FileName);

    FileType.ulReserved := 0;
    FileType.cbEncoding := 0;
    FileType.cbTag := 0;
    FileType.lpTag := nil;
    FileType.lpEncoding := nil;

    FileAttach.lpFileType := @FileType;
    Message.nFileCount := 1;
    Message.lpFiles := @FileAttach;
  end;

  MAPIModule := LoadLibrary(PChar(MAPIDLL));

  if MAPIModule = 0 then begin
    Result := -1;
  end
  else begin
    try
      @SM := GetProcAddress(MAPIModule,'MAPISendMail');
      if @SM <> nil then begin
        Result := SM(0,Application.Handle,Message,
          MAPI_DIALOG or MAPI_LOGON_UI,0);
      end
      else begin
        Result := 1;
      end;
    finally
      FreeLibrary(MAPIModule);
    end;
  end;

  if Result <> 0 then begin
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Error sending eMail (%d)', [Result]);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in Simple MAPI. If you were using Outlook Object Model or Extended MAPI, you could set a special MAPI property on the message before sending it to disable TNEF format.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I will look for more information about Extended MAPI. By the way, do you know when Outlook chooses TNEF and when not? The weird thing is that the end user always sent emails with PDFs and they were never TNEF. But if they create the email (with PDF attachment) using my program, the email becomes TNEF'ed.